# "- bash: ./YapHash: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos

I want to implement YapHash audio perceptual hash (https://github.com/viat/YapHash) in my project with MacOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6). The project itself had been tested on Linux and OS X 10.8.2. However, when I type this on my Macbook:

`REDui-MacBook-Air:YapHash red$ ./YapHash hash.cfg SPIT_01_ABeier.wav out1.csv`,

I got this message.

`-bash: ./YapHash: No such file or directory`.

It was fine on Linux OS, but I could not find the solution for the MacOS. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the `YapHash` executable exist in the current working directory?

Comment: Oh right, I should build the executable `YapHash` with Xcode. It leads to another problem though, but thank you!